# YAML Map Keys are read incorrectly

Tags: java, micronaut

When try to read map object from application.yml file with Keys containing spaces and starting with uppercase then keys are converted to kebab notation. But if root of the map is defined with Uppercase then everything works fine. Is it Micronaut default behaviour or is it a bug?

Below code gives Map with ["Key with space":[ "some more key", "some other key" ]]

```
  Key with space:
    - some more key
       some other key
```

But below code gives Map with ["k-ey with space":[ "some more key", "some other key" ]]

````
test:
  Key with space:
    - some more key
       some other key```
Im not able to find documentation for it.
````

Im using Micronaut Framework and trying to read configuration from YAML file.

Comment: For the benefit of readers, also reported at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/2564.

Comment: Actually I raised this so that someone could get me the answer for this unusual behaviour as in documentation i didn't found any clue.